# c# linq lambda The best way to fill the static List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class inheriting from another class
I am doing a query from the database
How do I fill in the static List without loop using linq lambda
If he finds a lot of data. this will not be fast
I want to escape from loop

```
     public class Currencys
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Curr_Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Curr_Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CentName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string curr_abbrivation { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string en_curr_name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string en_centname { get; set; }
}

public class test1 : Currencys
{
   
    static List<test1> _currenciesList;

    public static void Fill()
    {
        if (_currenciesList != null)
        {
            _currenciesList.Clear();
        }
       
        _currenciesList = new List<test1>();
        using (var context = new ContextFormeDb())
        {             
            var list = context.Currencies.ToList();
            list.ForEach(o=>
            {
                test1 _test1 = new test1();
                _test1.Curr_Id = o.Curr_Id;
                _test1.Curr_Name = o.Curr_Name;
                _test1.CentName = o.CentName;
                _test1.curr_abbrivation = o.curr_abbrivation;
                _test1.en_curr_name = o.en_curr_name;
                _test1.en_centname = o.en_centname;
                _currenciesList.Add(_test1);
            });
            
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything better than this?  without loop

```
            list.ForEach(o=>
            {
                test1 _test1 = new test1();
                _test1.Curr_Id = o.Curr_Id;
                _test1.Curr_Name = o.Curr_Name;
                _test1.CentName = o.CentName;
                _test1.curr_abbrivation = o.curr_abbrivation;
                _test1.en_curr_name = o.en_curr_name;
                _test1.en_centname = o.en_centname;
                _currenciesList.Add(_test1);
            });
```

Comment: If anything, linq introduces extra overhead besides the internal loop it uses. There is no magic there.

Comment: [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) method?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? The mapping to test1 entity seems overhead. Just use `context.Currencies.ToList()`

Comment: How can I query from the database? this query context.Currencies.ToList()   How can I fill _currenciesList  without loop

Comment: How can I use AutoMapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything better than this? without loop?

It depends on what you would call better. Faster? Probably not. Not much anyway. Easier to read and understand, easier to test, to debug, to change, to reuse? Probably.

Without Loop? there must be a loop somewhere, but it can be hidden inside a LINQ statement.

Whenever you want to fetch items from a database using entity framework, and you don't want to update the fetched items, always use `Select`, and select only the properties that you plan to use. Don't fetch the complete items, nor use `Include`. This will cost you overhead that you will only use if you update the fetched data.

So instead of:

```
var result = dbContext.Schools
    .Where(school => school.Name == "Hogwarts")
    .Include(school => school.Students)
    .ToList();
```

consider to use:

```
var result = dbContext.Schools
    .Where(school => school.Name == "Hogwarts")
    .Select(school => new
    {
        // Select only the properties that you plan to use
        Id = school.Id,
        Name = school.Name,
        ...

        students = dbContext.Students
            .Where(student => student.SchoolId == school.Id)
            .Select(student => new
            {
                 Id = student.Id,
                 Name = student.Name,
                 ...

                 // not needed, you know the value
                 // SchoolId = student.SchoolId,
            })
            .ToList(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

1. It will prevent the transfer of properties that you won't use
2. It will prevent that the fetched data will be copied to `DbContext.ChangeTracker`.
   If you don't put data that won't be changed in the ChangeTracker, then `SaveChanges` will be faster.

So in your case, your code would be easier to understand, easier to reuse, easier to test and debug, and without "for each" if you use `Select`:

```
var fetchedData = dbContext.Currencies
    .Where(currency => ...)             // if you don't want all currencies
    .Select(currency => new
    {
         // Select only the properties that you plan to use:
        Id = currency.Id,
        Name = currency.Name,
        ...
    })
    .ToList();
```

I used an anonymous type (`new` without specifying a class). This way you won't have to create a "dummy" class. The advantage is that you just write the properties and you'll have the object, you even have an "equality by value". If in future you need to add or remove a property, just do it, without any problem, no need to change your dummy class.

Disadvantage: you can't use it outside the current block, and certainly not as a return value of a procedure.

So if you need it outside your procedure:

```
.Select(currency => new Test1
{
    // Select only the properties that you plan to use:
    Id = currency.Id,
    Name = currency.Name,
    ...
})
.ToList(),
```

Answer (score -1):

If two lists are of the same type , you can use [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netcore-3.1).

if not and for any reason you need to map properties or its diffrent object type,  i would suggest configure [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/) in your app and like this you can easily convert you List from Type A to Type B and after that use AddRange

Comment: Is it possible to use an example   AutoMapper

Comment: the best source for example is the official documentation https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html